# Backlight turns off on high brightness

Tags: lg-g2, backlight

Mine LG G2 has a very strange backlight issue. The backlight is working on low brightness levels, but turns off after 40% of brightness. Under very bright light I still can see that the image is still present on the display, so the screen is working itself. When I change brightness level back under 40%, the backlight turns on again.

What could be faulty? Screen or motherboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that motherboard was faulty. I've replaced the motherboard and the issue has gone.